# How does Dir.entries() determine the order of the listed files in the array?

Tags: ruby

In my `/Users/name/website/posts` directory I have the following files:

```
$ ls -la
total 56
5 name  staff   160B 16 Apr 20:48 .
3 name  staff    96B 16 Apr 20:48 ..
1 name  staff   6.5K 16 Apr 20:47 bar.md
1 name  staff    11K 16 Apr 20:47 baz.md
1 name  staff   4.2K 16 Apr 20:47 foo.md
```

With this IRB session:

```
base = "/Users/name/website/posts"
#=> "/Users/bc/website/posts"
entries = Dir.entries(base)
#=> [".", "..", "bar.md", "foo.md", "baz.md"]
```

How is the order of the returned array determined?

Comment: Probably by the underlying file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although specific Ruby implementations may have their specific logic, it is arbitrary from the point of view of the specification.